# Saw a strange if statement in some legacy C code

Tags: c, legacy, evaluation

What I saw in an if statement was like this.

```
if((var = someFunc()) == 0){
   ...
}
```

Will the statement

```
(var = someFunc())
```

always return the final value of var no matter what environment we are in?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `if((var = someFunc()) == 0)` ? That would at least make sense...

Comment: Yes, an assignment always has the value of its lval. However, your code is probably wrong. I bet that what you saw instead was `if((var = someFunc()) == 0)`.

Comment: This shouldn't work. the second `=` probably should be `==`

Comment: The only strange elements are missing parenthesis and =. Otherwise this is standard code

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. The second was in fact an ==. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: That should result in a compilation error - attempt to assign not to lvalue or something similar.

Comment: I can often see code like this in a PHP application I'm maintaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a one-line way of assigning to a variable and comparing the returned value at the same time.

You need the parentheses around the assignment because the comparison operators have higher precedence than the assignment operator, otherwise `var` would be assigned the value of `someFunc() == 0`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: Reflected by the OP. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply wrong. `var` is assigned, and then its value is overwritten by a constant `0`. The return value of the function is therefore lost, and the `if` always fails. Most compilers would probably issue a warning about that nowadays, both because of the assignment within an `if` and because of the impossible `if` that results. The right way to do what was probably intended is

```
if((var = someFunc()) == 0) {
```

(Mind you, this *might* also be malicious code trying to introduce a vulnerability under the guise of a common newbie mistake. There was a case recently where someone tried to smuggle a check into the Linux kernel where they assigned the UID to 0 (i.e., root) while pretending to *check* for being root. Didn't work, though.)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, I use it all the time

if ((f=fopen(s,"r"))==NULL)
   return(fprintf(stderr,"fopen(%s,r) failed, errno=%d, %s\n",s,errno,strerror(errno)));
/* successfully opened file s, read from FILE *f as you like */

I also use it when I calloc() memory.

You're assigning the return value of someFunc (fopen or calloc in my cases) to a variable AND also testing that return value, it's a semantic shortcut assuming you'll never want to debug the assignment and the test separately.